# Recursive n Queens on nxn chess board implementation in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive Swift implementation for the solution of the classic puzzle: "How can we distribute n queens on a chess grid of n × n so that no queen can threaten another".

With existing code I encountered the following problems:

1. Code does not produce all the solutions for n<=8
2. Code does not product ANY solution for n>=9
3. Can't seem to compare solutions for n=8 (8x8) and larger because I compute the hash for each `Solution` class (board) by shifting bits which represent existence of queen or empty tile:

   ```
   public override var hash: Int {
       var hash = 0
       for i in 0...self.board.count-1 {
           for j in 0...self.board.count-1 {
               if self.board[i][j].state == .Queen {
                   hash |= 1
                   hash <<= 1
               } else {
                   hash <<= 1
               }
           }

       }
       return hash

   }
   ```

when board is >8x8 value gets corrupted as it is larger than 64 bits (swift Int is Int64). What's a good solution for that?

My current code:

```
import UIKit

public typealias Board = Array<Array<Cell>>

@objc protocol QueenPlacementDelegate : class {
    func solutionsFound(numOfSolutions : Int)
}

class QueenPlacement: NSObject {
    var boardView : TTTBoardView?
    var boardSize : Int = 0
    var solutions : Set<Solution>?
    weak var delegate : QueenPlacementDelegate? 
    private var startCondX : Int = 0
    private var startCondY : Int = 0


    func start() {

        if boardSize == 0 {
            print("Board size was not initialized")
            return
        }

        self.solutions = Set<Solution>()
        var done = false
        self.startCondX = 0; self.startCondY = 0;

        while (!done) {
            let solution = Solution(boardSize: self.boardSize)
            let board = solution.board
            self.placeQueen(startCondX, yLoc: startCondY, board: board)
            let solutionBoard = self.findSolutionForBoard(board)

            if self.numOfQueensOnBoard(solutionBoard) == self.boardSize {
                print("solution found")
                solution.board = solutionBoard
                self.solutions!.insert(solution)
            }

            done = self.advanceStartConditionsAndCheckIfDone()
            if (done) {
                if self.solutions!.count > 0 {
                    self.delegate!.solutionsFound(self.solutions!.count)
                }
            }

        }
    }

    func advanceStartConditionsAndCheckIfDone() -> Bool {
        startCondX++
        if startCondX >= self.boardSize {
            startCondX = 0
            startCondY++
            if startCondY >= self.boardSize {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }


    func placeQueen(xLoc : Int, yLoc : Int, board : Board) {
        board[xLoc][yLoc].state = .Queen
    }

    func findSolutionForBoard(board : Board) -> Board
    {
        let queensPlaced = self.numOfQueensOnBoard(board)
        if queensPlaced == self.boardSize {
            return board
        }
        else
        {
            for i in 0...self.boardSize-1 {
                for j in 0...self.boardSize-1 {
                    if self.canPlaceQueen(xLoc: i, yLoc: j, board: board) {
                        self.placeQueen(i, yLoc: j, board: board)
                    }
                }
            }
            let newQueensPlaced = self.numOfQueensOnBoard(board)

            // recursion exit conditions: could not place any new queen
            if newQueensPlaced > queensPlaced {
                self.findSolutionForBoard(board)
            } else {
                return board
            }
        }

        return board
    }

    func numOfQueensOnBoard(board : Board) -> Int {
        var queensPlaced = 0
        for i in 0...self.boardSize-1 {
            for j in 0...self.boardSize-1 {
                if board[i][j].state == .Queen {
                    queensPlaced++
                }
            }
        }
        return queensPlaced
    }


    func canPlaceQueen(xLoc xLoc : Int, yLoc : Int, board: Board) -> Bool {
        for i in 0...self.boardSize-1 {
            if board[i][yLoc].state == .Queen {
                return false;
            }
            if board[xLoc][i].state == .Queen {
                return false;
            }

        }

        var x : Int
        var y : Int
        x = xLoc; y = yLoc;
        while ++x < self.boardSize && ++y < self.boardSize {
            if board[x][y].state == .Queen {
                return false
            }
        }

        x = xLoc; y = yLoc;
        while --x >= 0 && ++y < self.boardSize {
            if board[x][y].state == .Queen {
                return false
            }
        }

        x = xLoc; y = yLoc;
        while ++x < self.boardSize && --y >= 0 {
            if board[x][y].state == .Queen {
                return false
            }
        }
        x = xLoc; y = yLoc;
        while --x >= 0 && --y >= 0 {
            if board[x][y].state == .Queen {
                return false
            }
        }

        return true

    }


    // singleton!
    static let sharedInstance = QueenPlacement()
    private override init() {}


}
```

What is wrong here?

P.S.
for easier reading - full code repo can be found [here](https://github.com/idokleinman/queens-puzzle)

Answer (score 0):

It's not an answer in a way that I don't know what is the problem with your version, but here is another one (looks working as I tested it), a little bit simplier (based on [Scala By Example](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf) - The N-Queens Problem).

```
func queens(n: Int) -> [[Int]] {

    guard n > 3 else {
        return [[Int]]()
    }

    func placeQueens(k: Int) -> [[Int]] {

        guard k > 0 else {
            return [[-1]] //stupid hack to let the app go to the for-loop in the * marked place
        }
        var res = [[Int]]()

        for var q in placeQueens(k - 1) { //* marked place

            if let first = q.first where first == -1 { //this is for removing the hacky -1
                q.removeAll()
            }

            for column in 1...n {

                if isSafe(column, queens: q) {
                    var solution = q
                    solution.append(column)
                    res.append(solution)
                }
            }
        }
        return res
    }
    return placeQueens(n)
}

func isSafe(column: Int, queens: [Int]) -> Bool {

    for (index, q) in queens.enumerate() {
        let dy = (index + 1) - (queens.count + 1)
        let dx = q - column
        let isDiagonal = dy * dy == dx * dx

        if q == column || isDiagonal {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

And if you want to draw the solutions out:

```
func drawTable(table: [Int]) -> String {
    var res = ""

    table.forEach {

        for column in 1...table.count {

            if $0 == column {
                res += "X "
            } else {
                res += ". "
            }
        }
        res += "\n"
    }
    return res
}
```

And

```
queens(4).forEach {
    print(drawTable($0))
}
```

Computing the 73712 solutions of `n = 13` took some minutes, above that you would probably run out of memory this way.

Comment: Can't say I really understand how this algorithm works `for var q in placeQueens(k - 1)` is it computing solutions for smaller nxn boards than the input one and then joining them together in some way?

Comment: @mindbomb basically in the line that you mentioned it computes valid lines (m x n where m is less than n, so you don't have the whole board there, just the first m valid lines), so there you can assume, that you have let's say the upper part of the chess board, where the queens are correctly placed. After that you check all possible columns if you can place a queen there, and if so, then it will be accumulated and returned.

Comment: And this joining is basically kind of "reversed", becuase of the (k - 1) thing. So when k == 0, it returns the empty array. Then k == 1, there you creating the first line. How? You check if it is valid to add a column to the empty array, which is always valid, so you will end up with n different first lines, which are returned to the k == 2, where you check that what columns can be added to those n first lines etc... Well it takes some time to understand, but this is a beautiful algorithm IMHO. Maybe the scala version is easier to understand (knowing the syntax)